# How to estimate intrinsic properties of a camera from data?

Tags: opencv, linear-algebra, camera-calibration

I am attempting camera calibration from a single RGB image (panorama) given 3D pointcloud

The methods that I have considered all require an intrinsic properties matrix (which I have no access to)[image]

The intrinsic properties matrix can be estimated using the [Bouguet’s camera calibration Toolbox](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/), but as I have said, I have a single image only and a single point cloud for that image.

So, knowing 2D image coordinates, extrinsic properties, and 3D world coordinates, how can the intrinsic properties be estimated?

It would seem that the `initCameraMatrix2D` function from the OpenCV (https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) works in the same way as the Bouguet’s camera calibration Toolbox and requires multiple images of the same object

I am looking into the [Direct linear transformation DLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation) and [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) with implementations https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gDW9zRmd0jF_7tHPqM0RgChBWz-dwPe1
but it would seem that both use the pinhole camera model and therefore find linear transformation between 3D and 2D points

Comment: By panorama, do you mean that your image is not rectilinear? Because this function assumes the pinhole camera model, in fact it says so in the first sentence of the page you linked.

Comment: @zteffi Not sure what rectilinear means, but its an image that is stitched out of many other images

Comment: It means that it preserves straight lines, as opposed to most projections  panorama images use (spherical, cylindrical, fisheye)

Comment: @zteffi I dont think it does by looking at lines in the image that suppose to be straight

Comment: OpenCV does have methods to project points and images to rectilinear space in [stiching module](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d0/dfa/group__stitching__warp.html), but it's mainly focused on stiching and projecting from spherical or fisheye projection into planar/rectilinear space is cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find my half year old source code, but from top of my head
`cx`, `cy` is optical centre which is width/2, height/2 in pixels
`fx`=`fy` is focal length in pixels (distance from camera to image plane or axis of rotation)

If you know that image distance from camera to is for example 30cm and it captures image that has 16x10cm and 1920x1200 pixels, size of pixel is 100mm/1200=1/12mm and camera distance (fx,fy) would be 300mm*12px/1mm=3600px and image centre is cx=1920/2=960, cy=1200/2=600. I assume that pixels are square and camera sensor is centered at optical axis.

You can get focal lenght from image size in pixels and measured angle of view.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the image is a panorama image...

Comment: Then you can assume that FF camera sensor has size of 36x24mm and 43.4mm diagonal. So you can get take diagonal in pixels, multiply it by lens focal length and divide it by sensor size diagonal to get fy and fx.